# How to create a new file in a folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a web application using javascript. I want to know

1) How can we create a new html file using javascript?

suppose I have a folder with location`examples\new Files\`. so I want that if some one click a button on my page then a javascript function runs and then creates a new html file in `new Files` folder with a specific text defined by the user.

Is there any way to do this or

Do i have to use different languages?

Comment: Do you want to create the file on server side or client side?

Comment: client side just for a reason

Comment: not on the client side, if you need it on the server side you can use AJAX with PHP, on the client side there is only filesystem and it works only in a few browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=filesystem

Comment: Normally browser doesn't support for security reasons. But, you can do this using Applet on any browser or using ActiveX objects on IE if client's browser permits.

Comment: a Java applet will do the work but there is lots of restrictions to protect unwanted actions. Still not sure, good luck.

Comment: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Comment: Why do you need to create a file in client site? Alternatively, you can store few information on client site using Cookies.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript that is used in browsers, like jQuery, has no access to the filesystem. It is a security restriction, otherwise any tom dick or harry on the internet could seriously mess up your computer.

The only filesystem access allowed is Cookies.

If you want to achieve something like this, you will need something like node.js, although I have no experience with node.

Comment: and the filesystem API?

Comment: http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

**Src**
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

    FileSaver.js is the solution to saving files on the client-side, and is perfect for webapps that need to generate files, or for saving sensitive information that shouldn't be sent to an external server.